# Can big-endian order be associated with the way Englishmen say the numbers under 100 and small-endian with the way Germans say those numbers?

Tags: arrays, binary, byte, endianness

I was thinking that for me and most people around me big-endian order of the bytes in memory seems the most natural way of arranging numbers.

You start with the most significant bytes, just like you write the numbers down and just like you spell them e.g **twenty-eight**

The most significant digit is written first and then you continue to write the next digits from the next most significant to the least significant This is the same way you say the numbers.

But the German people say this number in reverse. They say the number beginning with the least significant digit and then continue with the most significant digit.

I think this is a good analogy to endianness.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I was thinking that for me... Big-endian order of the bytes in memory seems the most natural way of arranging numbers... You start with the most significant bytes, just like you write the numbers down"*

Actually all binary data (zero/one bits) is written in MSB format. We *always* write the value as starting with MSD (Most-Significant Digit) on the left side, just like in real-life.

However, with having 8 slots within a byte to fill, we write the value itself starting from right side and increasing upwards by shifting to the left. PS: Endianness only applies at multi-byte level.

Summarily: In a single byte (holding a `< 100` value like **28** or even **99**)

- The value **28** is written as 28 (but since it's binary format, it looks like : `11100`).
- To write value we start at right side : `x x x 1 1 1 0 0` (where most-left `1`is the MSD).
- So the value itself is written in MSB style, but noted within the byte using LSB style of writing.
- There is no concept of endiannes within a single-byte value

*Example* : Imagine bits were slots for holding 0-9 digits...

We still write **28** as : `[0 0 0 0 0 0 2 8]` so the twenties part is placed like MSB but the whole value starts from the right as if written in LSB style.

Since a single byte does not have endianness, writing value **28** is never going to look like :
 `[0 0 0 0 0 0 8 2]` and never as `[2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0]` since that would give an incorrect **82** or incorrect **28 million** values.

> *"You start with the most significant bytes, just like you write the numbers down and just like you spell them e.g **twenty-eight**... But the German people say this number in reverse. They say the number beginning with the least significant digit and then continue with the most significant digit. 
>
> I think this is a good analogy to endianness."*

Sorry. No it isn't. It stopped being a good analogy as a soon as you mentioned that it involves one byte. A verbally spoken **eight-twenty** phrase could mean a different thing compared to the written decimal value **820**.

What about the English **eight-ten** (aka eight-teen) for value **18**? By your logic the Germans also say **eight-ten**, right? What happens to **eight-ten** when a machine is told to simply "reverse" the input when converting between English and German style?

Comment: I think that endianess still applies even within a single byte when data is transmitted over a wire. Some bits will be sent before some other bits. And what are those bits depends on the endianess of the transmission. EDIT: I really do not understand what do you mean by "So the value itself is written in MSB style, but noted within the byte using LSB style of writing."  What is the LSB style of writing? How is different than just writing down the number?